# Get layer attributes from xcf (GIMP) files C#

Tags: c#, file, attributes, gimp

I found some C# code a while ago which has helped me to obtain individual layer details from a XCF file. I can currently extract the layers 'x', 'y', 'layer name' and 'layer x' and 'layer y' details. Now I want the layers colour, content and rotation value (if rotated) and possibly any other details. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputPdf  = image_path + "offical_tour.xcf"; // GIMP file to load
        string outputPng = image_path + "output.png";       // output filename


        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection(inputPdf))
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    string layerFile = Path.Combine(image_path, image.Label + $".png");

                    image.Write(layerFile); // save the individual layers

                    // show some layer attributes
                    Console.WriteLine(image.Page.X + " x " + image.Page.Y + " = Layer:'" + image.Label + "' -- " + image.Width + " -- " + image.Height);
                }

                if (i++ == 0 || image.Compose != CompositeOperator.Over) continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No such thing a the "rotation" of a layer AFAIK (except maybe fore text layers). Is "colour" the tag colour in the UI?

Comment: Confused – I have a layer (c# seen as ‘label’) which in GIMP can be rotated, have colour and font types etc. I can’t believe it’s not possible to extract these details, and update them before being saved in their separate files??

Answer (score 0):

The information you seek is kept in Gimp as a "Parasite" of the layer, for instance:

```
(text "aaaa")
(font "Roboto Heavy")
(font-size 60)
(font-size-unit pixels)
(antialias yes)
(language "cad")
(base-direction ttb-rtl)
(color (color-rgb 0 0 0))
(justify center)
(box-mode dynamic)
(box-unit pixels)
(hinting yes)
```

This is a JSON-like object (but with a LISP/Scheme syntax). Since Gimp 2.10, the `text` element can be instead a `markup` one if specific parts of the text has a specific formatting:

```
(markup "<markup>plain<i>italic</i><b>bold</b></markup>")
```

Of course, I don't know how your library retrieves that information...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but, I'm a little unsure how to integrate (if that's the right word) this into C#.